# Joining 3 tables to a single table (Joining 4 Tables)

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 3 sales tables and 1 product table that contains all the product IDs. I need to combine the sales tables with the product table to get weekly sales.

[image: Tables and how they relate]

I have tried a few different join methods and unions. Every time I get the wrong output (either way too many or something like a cross join). Currently I have 3 different queries that I run, export those tables and manually combine the tables in excel.

An example of a join I have tried.

```
SELECT p1.product, p2.week, 
       p2.sales, p2.QTY,
       p3.sales, p3.QTY, 
       p4.sales, p4.QTY
FROM products_table p1 INNER JOIN aplha_sales p2 ON p1.alpha_product_id = p2.alpha_product_id
                       INNER JOIN beta_sales p3 ON p1.beta_product_id = p3.beta_product_id
                       INNER JOIN delta_sales p4 ON p1.delta_id = p4.delta_product_id
WHERE p2.week >= '2019-04-19';
```

I would like a table that has the following columns:

[image: Desired Output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the week in the joins, so that you just get that week's data from each table.

```
SELECT p1.product, p2.week, 
       p2.sales, p2.QTY,
       p3.sales, p3.QTY, 
       p4.sales, p4.QTY
FROM products_table p1 
INNER JOIN aplha_sales p2 ON p1.alpha_product_id = p2.alpha_product_id
INNER JOIN beta_sales p3 ON p1.beta_product_id = p3.beta_product_id AND p3.week = p2.week
INNER JOIN delta_sales p4 ON p1.delta_id = p4.delta_product_id AND p4.week = p2.week
WHERE p2.week >= '2019-04-19';
```

Note that this will only produce rows for weeks where all 3 products have had sales. You can use `LEFT JOIN` to make sales optional for 2 of the tables. But to make it optional for all 3 `XXX_sales` tables you need to join with another table that defines the weeks you want, and then `LEFT JOIN` with all the sales tables.

```
SELECT p1.product, w.week, 
       p2.sales, p2.QTY,
       p3.sales, p3.QTY, 
       p4.sales, p4.QTY
FROM products_table p1 
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT week FROM alpha_sales WHERE week >= '2019-04-19'
    UNION
    SELECT week FROM beta_sales WHERE week >= '2019-04-19'
    UNION
    SELECT week FROM delta_sales WHERE week >= '2019-04-19') AS w
LEFT JOIN aplha_sales p2 ON p1.alpha_product_id = p2.alpha_product_id AND p2.week = w.week
LEFT JOIN beta_sales p3 ON p1.beta_product_id = p3.beta_product_id AND p3.week = w.week
LEFT JOIN delta_sales p4 ON p1.delta_id = p4.delta_product_id AND p4.week = w.week
```

The `UNION` in the subquery will combine all the weeks that are in any of the sales tables. By default, `UNION` removes duplicates, so you won't get multiple rows for each week.

Comment: The first option, adding the weeks in the joins, gave me exactly what I needed. Thank you so very much. I am not sure why I didn't think about needing to specify the weeks for each of the tables. The second set of code, with the union will also come in handy for another similar situation I have. Thank you again!